# inside cloned div bound action with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, lightbox

My index page have some records where each record have one or more images associated with it.

Under record description there are list of image thumbs. where I have onclick events binded to js function which clone that image in different height inside  div showImage.

That's all fine.

Now I need to open that cloned image inside showImage div id in fullscreen mode using lightbox. 
Here's the code I'm having right now (it works but without fullscreen implementation)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function onPopUp() {
        var imageObject = $("img.details").first();
        var clonedObj = $(imageObject).clone();
        clonedObj.height("250px").width("300px");
        clonedObj.appendTo($("div#showImage"));

        $(".details").click(function (event) {
            //clone the clicked image
            var clone = $(this).clone();
            clone.height("250px").width("300px");
            //place it in the placeholder
            $('div#showImage').html(clone);
        });
    }
```

Backend code is asp.net mvc3 but I think that's not important here. For example purposes you can show me using html and css.
Thanks

**Update: That action that I want to bind onclick to cloned image inside showImage div can be alert message, for simplicity.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following solution is succ. completed my taks. 
I have to bind the click event only after the element is rendered, so I was achived this using:

```
$("#showImage").live("click", function (event) {
    alert('User clicked on "cloned element."');
});
```

.live will add an eventhandler on the window and check for the click event, then it checks the target, if it matches the event is triggered.

This way, any element added at anytime on the DOM will trigger this handler.

Many thanks to @Seb who point me to the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

you want to have `Event click` on an element which was created after `DOM`, in this case you want to use:

```
$('#cloned').bind('click', function() {
  alert('User clicked on "cloned element."');
});
```

[Here you have more information.](http://api.jquery.com/bind/)